# Javascript event handler or?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I have a question. I have a php file with queries of delete, insert, and to display data. There's a delete button in the file as well. To execute the delete query, it'll be something like

```
if($_POST['delete'])
 {
     //execute delete query
 }
```

which is in the PHP file. Now I have implemented ajax and I want to execute the delete query only when the button is clicked, but by using a function in javascript(I'm not too sure if this is the correct way or most suitable way). So everytime the delete button is clicked, a javascript function would be executed so that ajax would work. However it doesn't seem to do anything. Am I doing it the right way by using a javascript function to execute on button click or is there any other better ways? I'm doing this because I would like all the queries to be in one file so that's why I'm using an `if` statement to detect whether the button was clicked previously.

P.S. I'm using pure javascript codes as I am still learning so if there are any suggestions, I would prefer the raw codes rather than jQuery. Do comment if you would like to see the codes as I have asked a similar question before but I didn't find the answer I was looking for.

EDIT: Here are the codes

This is the javascript external file(for delete function only)

```
function deleteButtonClick(){
  //Perform the Ajax request to delete this user
  var del = document.getElementById("delete").innerHTML;
  var delRow = document.getElementById("deleteRow").innerHTML;
  var page = "database.php";
  var parameters = 'delete=true&deleteRow='+delRow;
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    if(confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this?')==true){

      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
         return false;
        }
      }
      xmlhttp.open("GET", page+"?"+parameters, true);
      xmlhttp.send(null);
     }
    }
```

These are the codes in the PHP file to execute the query

```
   // Delete Row
    if(isset($_POST['delete'])){
     $id = $_POST['deleteRow'];
     $query_string = "delete from $table_info where user_id='$id'";
     $result = @mysql_query($query_string);
     echo "row deleted";
     }
```

and these are the codes in the same PHP file, for the delete button at every row in a table

```
 echo "<td><input type='hidden' id='deleteRow' value=".$row['user_id']."/>";
 echo "<input type='button' id='delete' value='Delete' onclick='deleteButtonClick()'/></td>";
 echo "</tr></form>";
```

Comment: Please share your html and javascript code....

Comment: Also check your browser console to see whether there are any errors

Comment: Can you edit your question and display the relevant source code (html/js/php) without this it's impossible to know why it isn't working as intended. Thank you.

Comment: Looks like your Javascript is using `GET` while your PHP is expecting `POST`.

Comment: @DonovanM That's one, I've corrected it. Still doesn't work though.

Comment: **warning** your code is extremely vulnerable to sql injection attacks!

Comment: @DanielA.White Not to worry, this is just for an exercise I want to try and complete as I am new to PHP, javascript, and ajax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to code at the most simplest way to do this.

```
function deleteThis(count){

 var id  = document.getElementById("row"+count).innerHTML;
 var page = "database.php";
 var parameters = 'id='+id+'&action=delete';
 var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

 if(confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this?')==true){

 if(xmlhttp==null){
  alert("Your browser does not support ajax!");
  return false;
 }
 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
  document.getElementById("divTable").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText; 
 };
 xmlhttp.open("GET", page+"?"+parameters, true);
 xmlhttp.send(null);
 }
}
```

In the PHP file:

```
                                  .
                                  .
                            Some other codes
                                  . 
                                  .


function insertRow($name, $address, $phone, $gender, $nation){
  $table_info = "info";
  $query_string = "insert into $table_info(name, address, phone, gender, nation) values('$name', '$address', '$phone', '$gender', '$nation');";
  $result = @mysql_query($query_string) or die (mysql_error());  
}
?>

<?php
$action = rtrim($_REQUEST['action']);

if($action=="delete"){

 $id  = rtrim($_REQUEST['id']);
 echo deleteRow($id);
 echo update_database(); 
}
elseif($action=="insert"){

 $name = $_REQUEST['name'];
 $address = $_REQUEST['address'];
 $phone = $_REQUEST['phone'];
 $gender = $_REQUEST['gender'];
 $nation = $_REQUEST['nation'];

 echo insertRow($name, $address, $phone, $gender, $nation);
 echo update_database();
}
else{
 echo update_database();
}  
?>
```

Basically, I overlooked the capabilities of php and forgot that I can still manipulate the whole logic with functions. I removed the whole form and hidden input from the button entirely and used onclick to execute a function based on a variable `$count`. It increments every time a row is added which makes it easier as I confused myself with using the actual unique ID that was available in the database. All I had to do after that was request the data I needed and use it in my function to execture the query.